# Modify an object in Rust without having to copy the repository

Tags: rust

I would like to know if it is possible to modify, implement, or even add a new structure or data from a library structure installed using cargo in Rust.

Example:

```
pub struct Comment {
    pub author: User,
    pub body: String,
    pub created: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub id: String
}
```

And this structure does not have a specific macro, like debug, or I would like to implement a function - is it possible without having to download the project?

Comment: Do you just want to add a function to a foreign type? This is possible with extension traits.

Answer (score 2):

As Chayim Friedman mentioned, you can extend the functionality of structs using [extension traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html).

However, when you say that you want to 'add new data' it sounds like you would like to create a new struct that inherits from the `Comment` struct. There is no inheritance in rust, so this would not be possible.

You can create another struct with the first class as a member.

```rust
pub struct ExtendedComment {
    comment: Comment,
    views: usize,
    likes: usize,
}
```

Then to use the functionality provided by comment on your new struct, you would implement the traits that you want to use, and just call the method on `Comment`. Let's assume comment implements the method `foo` from trait `Bar`.

```rust
impl Bar for ExtendedComment {
   fn foo(&self) {
      self.comment.foo()
   }
}
```